# While building a mini app using JavaScript,HTML and CSS. I am getting 'undefined' value for the selected dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to build an interface where I can print the values that the user enters into a table and then it keeps updating. The basic functionality is working fine but the value from the drop down (both Test Type and Product Type) is showing as 'Undefined' when i make an entry in the table.
Can anyone please help me fix the issue.

```js
var row=1
var entry=document.getElementById("entry");
entry.addEventListener("click",displayDetails);

function displayDetails(){
    
    var name =document.getElementById("name").value;
    var email= document.getElementById("email").value;
    var TestType= document.getElementsByName("TP").value;
    var ProductType= document.getElementById("product_type").value;
    var IP= document.getElementById("txta_address").value;
    var Inputs= document.getElementById("num_inputs").value;

    if(name =='' || email == '' || TestType=='' || ProductType=='' || IP == ''|| Inputs == ''){
        alert("Please fill all the fields!");
        return;
    }



    var display = document.getElementById("display");

    var newRow = display.insertRow(row);

    var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = newRow.insertCell(4);
    var cell6 = newRow.insertCell(5);



    cell1.innerHTML = name;
    cell2.innerHTML = email;
    cell3.innerHTML = TestType;
    cell4.innerHTML = ProductType;
    cell5.innerHTML = IP;
    cell6.innerHTML = Inputs;
    

}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 1;
    padding: 1;
  }

  html{
      background : radial-gradient(rgba(179,255,255,0.5),rgba(255,255,255,0.5))
  }

  #nameDiv{
      margin-top: 50px;
  }

  .input{
      font-size: 25px;
      color: #004d00;
      font-style: initial;
      font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;    
      margin: 5px;
  }

  #entry{
      width : 150px;
      height: 60px;
      font-size: 25px;
      font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;    
      background-color: #05193d;
      color: whitesmoke;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      margin-top: 10px;
  }

  table{
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border: #05193d;
      width: 70%;
      margin: 50px auto;
      background-color: burlywood;
  }

  table,th,td{
      border: 5px solid black;
      padding: 30px;

  }

  th{
      font-size: 30px;
      font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
      font-weight: 700;
      color: #004d00;
  }
  
  td{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    color: crimson;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <title>Web Application</title>
 
</head>
<body>
 
<h2>User Input Form</h2>


<h4>Enter your details first</h4>
<div id="container">
 
  <div id="nameDiv" class="input"><strong>Enter your name: </strong><input id="name" type="text" placeholder="First Last" required/></div>
   <br>
   <br>
  <div class="input"><strong>Enter your Email: </strong><input id="email" type="text" placeholder="YOURNAME@DOMAIN.COM" required/></div>
   <br>
   <br>
  <div class="input"><label for="Test Types" id="tst_type"><strong>Test Type: </strong></label>
  <select size="1" id="tst_type" name="TP" >
  <option value=""> - Select - </option>
  <option value="Manufacturing">Manufacturing</option>
  <option value="Channel">Channel</option>
  <option value="DVT" >DVT</option></select>
  
  </div>
  
   <br>
   <br>
  <div class="input"><label for="Product Types" id="product_type"><strong>Product Type: </strong></label>
  <select size="1" id="product_type" name="PT">
  <option value=""> - Select - </option>
  <option value="RAID">RAID</option>
  <option value="RBOD">RBOD</option>
  <option value="EBOD">EBOD</option>
  <option value="iSCSI">iSCSI</option></select></div>
  

   <br>
   <br>
  <div class="input"><strong>IP Address: </strong><input id="txta_address" type="text" placeholder="10.10.10.10" required/></div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="input"><label for="No_of_Inputs"><strong>Number of Chasis Input: </strong></label><input id="num_inputs" type="text" placeholder="1" required/></div>
  <br>
  <br>
<button id="entry">Submit Information</button>
 
</div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
 
<table id="display">
 <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>Test Type</th>
  <th>Product Type</th>
  <th>IP Address</th>
  <th>Chasis Inputs</th>
 </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns a collection, not an element. You also have duplicate IDs for `product_type`, which is invalid HTML, so the `<select>` isn't being selected properly

Comment: @CertainPerformance, thanks a lot. The issue got fixed :)
One more question though, is there any way by which i get only the most recent entry made by the user and show it in the table. Right now the latest entry is coming after the previously made entry

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate mistakes.

First `var TestType= document.getElementsByName("TP").value;` and second duplicate `id`

`getElementsByName` returns a collection so you have to use like `var TestType = document.getElementsByName("TP")[0].value;`.

Secondly both `div` & `select` have same `id`. So the code is considering the `div` and giving `undefined` value

```js
var row = 1
var entry = document.getElementById("entry");
entry.addEventListener("click", displayDetails);

function displayDetails() {

  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var TestType = document.getElementsByName("TP")[0].value;
  var ProductType = document.getElementById("product_type_select").value;
  var IP = document.getElementById("txta_address").value;
  var Inputs = document.getElementById("num_inputs").value;

  if (name == '' || email == '' || TestType == '' || ProductType == '' || IP == '' || Inputs == '') {
    alert("Please fill all the fields!");
    return;
  }



  var display = document.getElementById("display");

  var newRow = display.insertRow(row);

  var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
  var cell5 = newRow.insertCell(4);
  var cell6 = newRow.insertCell(5);



  cell1.innerHTML = name;
  cell2.innerHTML = email;
  cell3.innerHTML = TestType;
  cell4.innerHTML = ProductType;
  cell5.innerHTML = IP;
  cell6.innerHTML = Inputs;


}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 1;
  padding: 1;
}

html {
  background: radial-gradient(rgba(179, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5))
}

#nameDiv {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.input {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #004d00;
  font-style: initial;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  margin: 5px;
}

#entry {
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  background-color: #05193d;
  color: whitesmoke;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin-top: 10px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: #05193d;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background-color: burlywood;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 30px;
}

th {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #004d00;
}

td {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  color: crimson;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
```

```html
<h2>User Input Form</h2>


<h4>Enter your details first</h4>
<div id="container">

  <div id="nameDiv" class="input"><strong>Enter your name: </strong><input id="name" type="text" placeholder="First Last" required/></div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="input"><strong>Enter your Email: </strong><input id="email" type="text" placeholder="YOURNAME@DOMAIN.COM" required/></div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="input"><label for="Test Types" id="tst_type"><strong>Test Type: </strong></label>
    <select size="1" id="tst_type" name="TP">
      <option value=""> - Select - </option>
      <option value="Manufacturing">Manufacturing</option>
      <option value="Channel">Channel</option>
      <option value="DVT">DVT</option>
    </select>

  </div>

  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="input"><label for="Product Types" id="product_type"><strong>Product Type: </strong></label>
    <select size="1" id="product_type_select" name="PT">
      <option value=""> - Select - </option>
      <option value="RAID">RAID</option>
      <option value="RBOD">RBOD</option>
      <option value="EBOD">EBOD</option>
      <option value="iSCSI">iSCSI</option>
    </select>
  </div>


  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="input"><strong>IP Address: </strong><input id="txta_address" type="text" placeholder="10.10.10.10" required/></div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="input"><label for="No_of_Inputs"><strong>Number of Chasis Input: </strong></label><input id="num_inputs" type="text" placeholder="1" required/></div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="entry">Submit Information</button>

</div>
<script src="main.js"></script>

<table id="display">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Test Type</th>
    <th>Product Type</th>
    <th>IP Address</th>
    <th>Chasis Inputs</th>
  </tr>

</table>
```